# Find the specific email from list of email which are separated by comma list of email is store in one table field

Tags: mysql

i have one table  which contain list of email 
in likes_vegetable contain email of who likes vegetable similarly 
   Likes_fruits contain emails of who like fruits

Create Query

```
CREATE TABLE emailList
(
Likes_Vegetables varchar(50),
Likes_Fruits varchar(50),
Drinks varchar(50)
)
```

Insert Query

```
INSERT INTO emailList(Likes_Vegetables,Likes_Fruits,Drinks)
       VALUES("aaa@example.com,ff@example.com","bbb@example.com,dd@example.com,'ee@example.com'","hh@example.com,gg@example.com,cc@example.com")
```

i want to found ff@example.com present in which list. or I want to know that whether  ff@example.com is in like_vegetable  field or ff@example.com is in like_fruits  field

What is the query for this?

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET("aaa@example.com",Likes_Vegetables) from emaillist
```

i tried this its giving output 1
but for others its showing wrong

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET("ff@example.com",Likes_Vegetables) from emaillist
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this-

```
select * from emaillist where FIND_IN_SET("ff@gmail.com",Likes_Vegetables)
```